# Want to add <input> html element with autoincrement id using ANGULAR

Tags: angularjs

I have following html content

```
<div id="abc"></div>

<input type="button" name="xyz" value="Add Input">
```

I want that when we click on above "Add Input" button then following input tag should be appended with autoincrement id in "abc" div content.

```
<input id="mx1" value="">
```

When first time we click then it should append   `<input id="mx1" value="">`  , when we click next time, then it should append `<input id="mx2" value="">`, like this.

How to do this in Angular ? Will it easy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `ng-repeat`

```
<div id="abc">
    <input type="text" id="{{input.id}}" ng-repeat="input in inputs">
</div>

<input type="button" name="xyz" value="Add Input" ng-click="addInput()">
```

In your controller

```
$scope.inputs = [];
$scope.addInput = function() {
   id = $scope.inputs.length + 1
   $scope.inputs.push({
     id: id,
     value: 'value'
   })       
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/fu7yL83m/

Comment: I just modified your given sample code with some extra info. It works as i want https://jsfiddle.net/fu7yL83m/7/

Answer (score 1):

in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in inputData">
    <input id="mx{{$index}}" ng-model="data.value">         
</div>
<input type="button" name="xyz" ng-click="addButton()" value="Add Input">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.inputData = []; //declare an empty array

$scope.addButton = function(){

    $scope.inputData.push({value: ''}); //push new object to this array

}
```